# The best way to use variables in another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick, onitemclicklistener

I have a doubt related intent in java android. I have 2 class[**ClickSubSectionAnswer** and **ListClickHandler**], which is in Main Activity. My doubt is know how the best way to use the variable auxurl and           auxtagdb in a new activity called **Layout_middle_answer.class**. I do not know how to use(to transfer, to send) these variables in my new activity. Any tips ?

**Class 1 and Class 2 :**

```
 public void ClickSubSectionAnswer(View view){
         selsub = view.getId();
         String tagsub = view.getTag().toString();
         UpdateAnsList myUpdate = new UpdateAnsList(this);      
         myUpdate.StartUpdateAnsList(selsub,tagsub);
         auxurl = myUpdate.url;
         auxtagdb = myUpdate.tagdb;
         ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView11);
         listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListClickHandler());

    }
    public class ListClickHandler implements OnItemClickListener{

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Layout_middle_answer.class);
            //intent.putExtra(auxtagdb, 0);
            //intent.putExtra(auxurl,1);

            startActivity(intent);


        }

    }
```

Comment: What type of `auxtagdb` and `auxurl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start a new activity u can send data with an intent. For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, newActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra(KEY, data);
```

If the data is custom object this class must extends from Parcelable so it could be send with an Intent.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Intent` is a great way to transfer data between activities. But it depend on your variable's type. Some types can't not transfer directly but you can serialize it to `String` or `byte` to transfer.